# FileOutputStream write method (int) java

Tags: java, input, stream, writer

From the API the method write(int byte) should take an int representing a byte so in that way it when EOF comes it can return -1.
However it's possible doing the following thing:

```
FileOutputStream fi = new FileOutputStream(file);
    fi.write(100000);
```

I expected to not compile as the number exceeds the byte range. 
How does the JVM interpret it exactly?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Always... but always... refer to the docs :)

Comment: First of all 100000 is a valid int, so there shouldn't be compilation error

Comment: You're confusing read and write. `InputStream.read()` returns an int so that it can return -1 to signal EOF.

Comment: @JBNizet and Maroun Maroun yep you both right the -1 thing does not apply in this case.. so then why they chose an int as parameter and not a simple mere byte?

Comment: probably to easily be able to read from one stream and write to another without having to convert the read int to a byte. You can pass a byte to a method taking an int as argument, but you can't pass an int to a method taking a byte as argument.

Comment: @Rollerball. For one, every binary operation results in at least as of type `int`. So, everytime you would have to cast to byte to call the method.

Comment: @RohitJain And add to that all the nuisances from `byte` being a signed quantity. I don't think *anyone* has *ever* made use of `byte` as a signed integer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [`OutputStream.write(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#write%28int%29) doc:

> Writes the specified byte to this output stream. The general contract for write is that one byte is written to the output stream. The byte to be written is the eight low-order bits of the argument b. **The 24 high-order bits of b** are ignored.

Emphasis mine.

Note that the method takes an `int`. And since *100000* is a valid integer literal, there is no point of it being not compiling.

Answer (score 1):

Where did you read that part about EOF and -1?

The [method just writes one byte](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#write%28int%29), which for some reason is passed along as an int.

> Writes the specified byte to this output stream. The general contract for write is that one byte is written to the output stream. The byte to be written is the eight low-order bits of the argument b. The 24 high-order bits of b are ignored.

---

> I expected to not compile as the number exceeds the byte range

No, this will compile okay. The compiler just looks for an `int`. (A `long` would not compile).

Everything except the lowest 8 bits will be ignored.

Comment: then why did not they choose to use a byte as parameter?

Comment: @Rollerball `byte` is signed and it would create all kinds of inconveniences. `short` has issues with widening conversions happening implicitly in operations inolving integer literals. `int` is just the most convenient choice.